# Neither the property nor one of the methods exists and has public access in the class, but exists

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a bit of a problem that I don't understand at all.

> Neither the property "selected" nor one of the methods "selected()", "getselected()"/"isselected()"/"hasselected()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Twig\Components\MenuItem".

Selected property is well and beautifully defined and in public. I don't know what the problem is

```php
// 
<?php

namespace App\Twig\Components;

use Symfony\UX\TwigComponent\Attribute\AsTwigComponent;

#[AsTwigComponent]
final class MenuItem
{
    public string $selected;
}
```

```html
       :class="{'rotate-180': (selected ==='{{ this.selected }}')}"
      ></i>
    </a>
  {% else %}
    <a
      x-init="console.log('{{ this.selected }}')"
```

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#faf6a13a77) - Please provide more details to reproduce the error

Answer (score 1):

When creating [`TwigComponents`](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-twig-component/current/index.html) you don't need to do `{{ this.var }}` to reference the variable created in the PHP class, you can just use `{{ var }}`.

Changing your code to `{{ selected }}` instead of `{{ this.selected }}` should resolve the issue.